# Angular UI Bootstrap Modal strips id and class attributes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

[Live Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/WSbSqeDBU2JyhTmsqbZ4?preview&p=preview)

Adding the following [Angular UI Bootstrap Modal](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/#modal):

```
<div id="my-id" class="my-class" modal="opened">
  <p>Modal Here</p>
</div>
```

results in:

```
<div class="modal ng-scope">
  <p>Modal Here</p>
</div>
```

Why the `id` and `class` attributes are stripped?

I would like to set some CSS styling on the dialog, e.g. dialog's width, or styling some dialog's inner elements. How could I achieve that?

Comment: `modal` is a convenience directive of `dialog` which has far more flexibility and options.

Comment: I tried to set the width on an inner `div`, but the result is quite bad.

Answer (score 12):

Because I just came across this irritating issue myself and the documentation and default behavior isn't obvious.  You can now pass in additional classes via the $modal.open() method using the `windowClass` option:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'templateUrl.html',
      controller: Controller,
      windowClass: 'custom-css-class',
      ...
    });
```

Can't set an ID though which is lame. More info in the official [angular-ui modal docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).

Comment: yeah. i've been struggling for days. finally here's the answer.

Comment: Some answers make life so easy. Kudos.

Answer (score 9):

Here's the [github issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/197) explaining why the id is being stripped.

As for the class, I'm not sure why's that stripped, but you can use [$dialog options](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/dialog) to specify the class (which will fix your issue):

```html
<div id="my-id" modal="opened" options="{dialogClass: 'modal my-class'}">
  <p>Modal Here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like setting `dialogClass` causes the modal not to show up properly: http://plnkr.co/edit/PyDqFwY8ejhZVqvzjwq6?preview&p=preview. I guess it's because setting `dialogClass` removes the `modal` class. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: I guess I could set `dialogClass: 'modal my-class'`, but it looks a bit hacky. Is there a better way?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about the modal class. Don't know of any other way, haven't used this too much.

Comment: It seems like this was stripped in the newest release of `$modal`, so it seems. Pretty breaking change for me honestly.

Comment: $dialog has been removed: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src